# eclipse android : edittext input will be the output of other edittext

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 3 edittext, 1st for input the price, 2nd for input the percentage and 3rd for the output of them calculated.example:
1st input is 100000, second input is 30, then the 3rd edittext will automatically fill itself with 30000 .Is it possible to do that?

thanks in advance,

regards,
george

Comment: Yes possible. You can use TextWatcher on your EditText and handle whatever you want to do with your user Input data Immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You can use editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher) for this.

**EDIT1**

```
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            if (text1.length() != 0) {
                int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);

                int input2 = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());

                int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                editText3.setText(output + "");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you give an example

Answer (score 0):

Add [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //'calculatedPercentage' is the calculated value
        editText3.setText(calculatedPercentage);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher for this with your EditText and use onTextChanged method for your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the TextWatcher like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```